# enter xxx.github.io then shown `There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.`

Tags: github

I have tried to deploy hero on my github.(https://github.com/tsungruihon/tsungruihon.github.io). I have followed the hexo tutorial and github tutorial. But when i enter `tsungruihon.github.io` on the browser, it shown me `There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.`

Here's my `blog/_config.yml`

```
url: http://petertsengruihon.com
root: /
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title/
permalink_defaults:

deploy:
  type: git
  repo: git@github.com:tsungruihon/tsungruihon.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

And my CNAME file is below:

```
petertsengruihon.com
```

Please give me some hint.

Comment: It looks like this has been resolved now?

Comment: [Github tutorial](https://pages.github.com) is showing how to create simple page for site. But your repository is empty, no pages exists at your site. You cannot use this site because it is empty.

Comment: @Andrew thanks Andrew, i try now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it and how to automate the process:

### 1) Install [hexo-deployer-git](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-deployer-git)

`$ npm install hexo-deployer-git --save`

### 2) Setup deployer in your main `_config.yml` by adding the following code

```
# Deployment
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/tsungruihon/tsungruihon.github.io
```

### 3) Generate your blog

`$ hexo clean` then
`$ hexo generate`

### 4) Deploy

`$ hexo deploy`

This command will automatically deploy your blog.

**BONUS:** Add the following script to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "hexo clean && hexo generate && hexo deploy",
},
```

and after that you can simply type `npm run deploy` to generate and deploy your site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your setup is all correct, it may take some time for github to display your site on that URL

Comment: I guess that maybe i haven't setup a gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

Currently your repo only has a README:

http://github.com/tsungruihon/tsungruihon.github.io/tree/cf22320

If you want to build a page, you might start by... building a page.